# Morita equivalence of Lie groupoids

Tags: ct.category-theory, lie-groupoids

I am trying to understand what exactly is the Morita equivalence of Lie groupoids.

I am reading Ieke Moerdijk’s notes [Orbifolds as groupoids](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0203100).

> A homomorphism $\phi:\mathcal{H}\rightarrow \mathcal{G}$ between Lie groupoids is called an equivalence (Morita equivalence) if
>
> - the composition $G_1\times_{G_0} H_0\xrightarrow{\pi_2}G_1\xrightarrow{t}G_0$ is a surjective submersion.
> - the square
>   $$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
>   \mathcal H_1 @>\phi>> \mathcal G_1 \\
>   @V(s, t)VV  @V(s, t)VV \\
>   \mathcal H_0 \times \mathcal H_0 @>\phi \times \phi>> \mathcal G_0 \times \mathcal G_0
>   \end{CD}$$
>
> is a fibered product of manifolds.

Here $\mathcal{H}_1$ denotes morphism set and $\mathcal{H}_0$ denotes objects set. Similarly $\mathcal{G}_0,\mathcal{G}_1$ are denoted.

I do not really understand what exactly this says. I am trying to understand what this means in the case of simple examples but did not succeed.

The notion of equivalence of categories I know is the following:

> A functor $\mathcal{F}:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{D}$ is called an equivalnece of categories if there is another functor $\mathcal{G}:\mathcal{D}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ such that $\mathcal{F}\circ\mathcal{G}$ is naturally equivalent to the identity functor on $\mathcal{D}$ and $\mathcal{G}\circ\mathcal{F}$ is naturally equivalent to identity functor on $\mathcal{C}$.

Do we have something similar to this when we say Morita equivalence of Lie groupoids?

Any comments are welcome.

**Edit**: As [suggested](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301054/morita-equivalence-of-lie-groupoids#comment749405_301054) by **Benjamin Steinberg**, I tried to see that the first condition is saying $\phi$ is an essentially surjective functor and the second condition is saying that $\phi$ is fully faithful.

I was able to see that the first condition implies that the functor is essentially surjective. I have deleted the proof here and added it in comments ([1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301054/morita-equivalence-of-lie-groupoids#comment756932_301054) [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301054/morita-equivalence-of-lie-groupoids#comment756933_301054)) so that the question does not look big.

Now, I need to see that the second condition implies $\phi$ is full and faithful, i.e., given $x,y\in \mathcal{H}_0$ I have to see that the induced map $\mathcal{H}(x,y)\rightarrow \mathcal{G}(\phi(x),\phi(y))$ is a bijective map. I was able to see that this is surjective (proof in [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301054/morita-equivalence-of-lie-groupoids#comment756934_301054)) but could not see how this is injective.

Let $\gamma,\gamma':x\rightarrow y$ be such that $\phi(\gamma)=\phi(\gamma')$. How does one prove $\gamma=\gamma'$. I can not really say what exactly does it mean to say two arrows are equal.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Once I prove that this means $\phi$ is essentially surjective and fully faithful, it gives some justification for declaring this to be a good notion of equivalence of Lie groupoids from following result.

> A functor $F:A\rightarrow B$ is fully faithful and essentially surjective if an only if there is a functor $G:B\rightarrow A$ with two natural isomorphisms(natural transformations) $\alpha:FG\Rightarrow id_A$ and $\beta:GF\Rightarrow id_B$.

So, this would give the notion of equivalence that I was looking for. This would give an equivalence of categories, with no smooth structure involved.

[Orbifolds as stacks?](https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.4160) in page no. *8* says that there is no analogous theorem for smooth functors between Lie groupoids, there are many fully faithful essentially surjective smooth functors between Lie groupoids with no continuous (I guess he mean smooth) weak inverse ($G:B\rightarrow A$ that I have mentioned above, he is calling it weak inverse).

Further it says,

> Not every fully faithful and essentially surjective smooth functor between two Lie groupoids should be considered **an equivalence of Lie groupoids** (cf., not every smooth bijection between manifolds is a diffeomorphism).

He then says the accepted definition is what I have given above.

**Question $1$**: How does one see that the condition *2* says the functor is faithful.

**Question $2$**: Yes, just declaring a smooth functor that is essentially surjective, fully faithful is not a good notion of equivalence of Lie groupids. What is the motivation behind declaring the definition that I have given above is a good notion of equivalence of categories?

What is the extra thing we get if we declare morphisms between Lie groupoids to be not just equivalence of categories (fully faithful and surjective) but Morita equivalence of categories?

Comment: You should first check if you had discrete groupoids this would boil down to a full and faithful functor (that's what the second condition gives) Such that every object of G is isomorphic to one on the image (that's what the first condition says). Now Moerdijk is writing this diagramatically to build in the appropriate smoothness.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg thanks for your comment. I do not completely understand your comment. Are you saying when $G,H$ are discrete groupoids Morita equivalence is just a full and faithful functor?

Comment: With each object isomorphic to one on the image.

Comment: Then this would be just usual equivalence of categories. Right? Any full faithful essentially surjective functor is an equivalence.. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_categories How does one get idea of generalising this notion of equivalence to the notion of Morita equivalence?? @BenjaminSteinberg

Comment: It is just natural equivalence for discrete groupoids. Now you want to write fully faithful and essentially surjective in a diagramatic way so you can do a smooth  version.  Convince yourself first that the first condition is essentially surjective in the discrete case and the second is fully faithful.

Comment: By the way, Morita equivalence of Lie groupoids can also be formulated in terms of principal bibundles that makes it look more like Morita contexts in ring theory.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I will convince my self that as you said Morita equivalence of discrete groupoids is just natural equivalence.. that would be my first goal now.. I will then ask more questions... I did not know about Morita in Ring theory. Thanks for saying something extra.

Comment: I don't think its a question of generalizing to the smooth manifold setting. What you have seen is Moerdijk's definition gives the natural definition for discrete groupoids so it is a reasonable definition in the smooth setting.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I don’t think I completely understand your comment. Can you explain little more.

Comment: You cannot reformulate in more general categories like the smooth category in as simple a way as for discrete groupoids.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg thanks.. Do you want to say something more or you think this is just nothing but an obvious way to define equivalence in case of Lie groupoids.

Comment: I think it is the natural way.

Comment: Let $b\in G_0$. To prove the functor $\phi$ is essentially surjective, we need to prove that $b$ is isomrorphic to $\phi(a)$ for some $a\in H_0$.

As $G_1\times_{G_0} H_0\xrightarrow{\pi_2}G_1\xrightarrow{t}G_0$  surjective, there exists an element $(g,h)\in G_1\times_{G_0}H_0$ such that $t(\pi_1(g,h))=b$. By $(g,h)\in G_1\times_{G_0}H_0$ we mean that $s(g)=\phi(h)$.

Comment: As $\pi_1(g,h)=g$, the condition $t(\pi_1(g,h))=b$ mean that $t(g)=b$. This says we have $g\in G_1$ such that $s(g)=\phi(y)$ and $t(g)=b$ i.e., we have arrow $g:\phi(y)\rightarrow b$. 

As we are in groupoids, every arrow is an isomorphism, which says $b$ is isomorphic to $\phi(y)$ for some $y\in H_0$ concluding that the functor $\phi:H\rightarrow G$ is essentially surjective.

Comment: Coming to Fully faithfull property, I tried to see that, given $x,y\in \mathcal{H}_0$, the map $\mathcal{H}(x,y)\rightarrow \mathcal{G}(\phi(x),\phi(y))$ is a bijective map. Let $\eta:\phi(x)\rightarrow \phi(y)$ be an arrow i.e., an element of $\mathcal{G}(\phi(x),\phi(y))$. See that, we have $(\phi,\phi)(x,y)=(s,t)(\eta)$. As the diagram is commutative, there exists $\gamma\in \mathcal{H}_1$ such that $(s,t)(\gamma)=(x,y)$ and $\phi(\gamma)=\eta$ i.e.,
$\phi(x\rightarrow y)=\eta$. Thus, $\mathcal{H}(x,y)\rightarrow \mathcal{G}(\phi(x),\phi(y))$ is a surjective map.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg : Hello, please look at my edited question.. You said in comments that "Morita equivalence of Lie groupoids can also be formulated in terms of principal bibundles".. Can you give some reference for this way of defining Morita equivalnece. I have started studying bibundles so this might be relevant.

Comment: Moerdijk has a survey paper on groupoids talking about stuff as well as his two papers on classifying toposes of continuous groupoids.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Can you Lin for which paper you are referring to, thank you ::

Comment: I don't have links. Two of the papers have classifying Topos of continuous groupoids in the title. The survey I forget the name of.

Comment: Some one I know also said there is a survey paper by Moerdijk but even they don’t remember title... I could see papers classifying toppa of continuous groupoids http://archive.numdam.org/article/CTGDC_1990__31_2_137_0.pdf and https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1988-310-02/S0002-9947-1988-0973173-9/S0002-9947-1988-0973173-9.pdf it has two parts @BenjaminSteinberg

Comment: In the second condition, the universal property of the pullback says that given $\phi(g) : \phi (x) \rightarrow \phi (y)$ there's exactly one $g : x \rightarrow y$ with image $\phi(g)$. The question 2 can be answered by understanding that the above definition allows an inverse smooth morphism. Another motivation is that Morita equivalent groupoids present the same stack (after localization by Morita equivalence, you get the category of smooth stacks)

Comment: @user40276 It might be very easy but I still do not understand how you are saying that for question 1... can you say little more... can you make your comment as an answer(atleast for question 2 if you think 1 is silly)...

Comment: The pullback means that $\{ ((x, y), h) | \ h : x \rightarrow y \in H \} = H_1 \cong \{ ((x, y), g) | \  g :\phi(x) \rightarrow \phi (y) \in G \}$.

Comment: @user40276 Oh, Yes Yes.. I somehow missed it. Thanks..

Comment: _What is the extra thing we get if we..._ -- the next thing you wrote after that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Morita equivalence implies the usual notion of equivalence of categories... so, what is that extra thing that property of morita equivalence has which equivalence of categories does not have... does this make it little clear now?

Comment: In rather general categories, epimorphisms aren't particularly well-behaved, even in concrete categories in which epimorphisms have surjective underlying set-functions. Just asking that the map $G_1\times_{G_0} H_0\xrightarrow{\pi_2}G_1\xrightarrow{t}G_0$ is an epimorphism (between groupoids internal to a general category with enough pullbacks) doesn't allow one to prove much about that class of maps, for instance, stability properties. It's better to ask that it is at least a regular epi. See eg http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/30/55/30-55abs.html

Comment: I do not really understand your comment

Comment: "Essentially surjective" is equivalent, for a functor between groupoids internal to a concrete category (so where the objects have underlying sets), that the map $G_1\times_{G_0} H_0\xrightarrow{\pi_2}G_1\xrightarrow{t}G_0$ is surjective. In more general settings, one would replace "surjective" by "is an epimorphism", but this is too general a condition. Surjective maps of manifolds (as you are particularly considering here) are badly behaved in general. Surjective submersions form a pretopology, which is the right amount of structure you need.

Comment: It's coming to the point where I would be writing a survey-article-length piece (or a book) to address all your questions. Please have a good read of the references I'm giving, which do in fact contain most if not all of the answers you are looking for. If this is indeed all build-up for a PhD project (as you've said elsewhere), then reading the literature pointed out to you and following the references therein is one of the most important skills you will be learning during a PhD. As a last comment, please ponder the proof of "... fully faithful and essentially surjective if and only if ..."

Comment: @DavidRoberts sorry, that was only half of my comment.. I was going to edit it.. I understand why just surjective/essentially surjective is not sufficient.. I was trying to edit last line of my question where ”... allow morphisms” I now understand why it did not make sense to you :)

Comment: ...and why it totally fails in the case of Lie groupoids. Think of some examples of Lie groupoids to try this on. Check out these notes: http://www.math.toronto.edu/mein/teaching/MAT1341_LieGroupoids/

Comment: @DavidRoberts “It's coming to the point where I would be writing a survey-article-length piece (or a book) to address all your questions”... I do not really know what to say for this.. Apologies... i will read what you have suggested... Thank you :)

Comment: One more: there is a definition of a 1-arrow in a 2-category being an "equivalence", and all of this is about the question of what 2-category do you want with objects being the Lie groupoids (or more generally, internal groupoids in some other category), so that the "equivalences" do in fact capture all the arrows between groupoids that are for all practical purposes indistiguishable by categorical means. It's also worth noting the origin of the phrase 'Morita equivalence' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morita_equivalence , and that the groupoids version is defined to make the analogy thorough.

Comment: I typeset the commutative diagram from your image and added some links.  But in the commutative diagram and the remainder of the question, you denote objects by calligraphic letters $\mathcal G$ and $\mathcal H$; but, right before the diagram, you refer to $G_1 \times_{G_0} H_0  \xrightarrow{\pi_1} G_1 \xrightarrow t G_0$.  Should these be calligraphic?  (I tried to compare to the Moerdijk article you linked, but, unless I was in the wrong place, it does not seem to use calligraphic letters at all.)

Answer (score 3):

(*Using the same notations as mentioned in the question*.)

Let $g \in \mathcal{G}_0$. Then the first condition  ensures the existence of a $(\gamma , x) \in   \mathcal{G}_1 \times{_{s,\mathcal{G}_0,\phi
_0}} \mathcal{H}_0 $ such that $t(\gamma)=g$ and $s(\gamma)=\phi_0(x)$. *Essential surjectivity* follows from the fact that $\mathcal{G}$ is a groupoid.

The second condition ensures that there exists a diffeomorphism
$\mathcal{F}:\mathcal{H}_1 \rightarrow \mathcal{G}_1 \times_{\mathcal{G}_0 \times \mathcal{G}_0} (\mathcal{H}_0 \times \mathcal{H}_0)$
given by $\gamma \mapsto \bigl( \phi_1(\gamma),(s(\gamma),t(\gamma) ) \bigr)$. The smooth structure on $\mathcal{G}_1 \times_{\mathcal{G}_0 \times \mathcal{G}_0} (\mathcal{H}_0 \times \mathcal{H}_0)$ is induced by the bijection
$$(\mathcal{G}_1 \times_{s,\mathcal{G}_0,\phi_0} \mathcal{H}_0)\times_{t \circ \pi_2, \mathcal{G}_0, \phi_0} \mathcal{H}_0 \rightarrow \mathcal{G}_1 \times_{(s,t), \mathcal{H}_0 \times \mathcal{H}_0, \phi \times \phi}(\mathcal{H}_0 \times \mathcal{H}_0)$$ given by $\bigl((\gamma,h_1),h_2) \bigr) \mapsto \bigl( \gamma, (h_1,h_2) \bigr)$.

Now, since $\operatorname{Hom}(h,k)$ is a closed submanifold of $\mathcal{H}_1$ for all $h,k \in \mathcal{H}_0$, hence $$\phi\rvert_{\rm{Hom}(h,k)}= \operatorname{pr}_1 \circ \mathcal{F}\rvert_{\operatorname{Hom}(h,k)}: \operatorname{Hom}(h,k) \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(\phi(h),\phi(k))$$ is a diffeomorphism for all $h,k \in \mathcal{H}_0$. Hence the second condition is **not only** saying $\phi\rvert_{\operatorname{Hom}(h,k)}$ is a bijection but in fact a diffeomorphism.

**Note**: *The question was asked a long time back and it seems the issue has been resolved in the comments section but just for the sake of completeness for the future readers I added an answer here.*

Comment: I did a spot of proofreading, and, while I was editing, noticed that all $\phi$s were `\mathcal`d.  Since this makes no difference (see $\phi$ `\phi` vs. $\mathcal{\phi}$ `\mathcal{\phi}`), I removed it, hopefully doing no harm to your intention.

Comment: @LSpice Yh it's fine.

Comment: @AdittyaChaudhuri Could you please elaborate on why $\mathrm{pr}_1\circ\mathcal F|_{\mathrm{Hom}(h,k)}$ should be a diffeomorphism?

Comment: Oh, I think I see why: $\mathcal F|_{\mathrm{Hom}(h,k)}$ maps $\mathrm{Hom}(h,k)$ diffeomorphically onto $\mathcal H\times_{\mathcal G_0\times \mathcal G_0} \{(h,k)\}$ and the latter is identified with $\mathrm{Hom}(\phi(h),\phi(k))$.