# unit element under map of stacks $B\mathcal{G}\rightarrow B\mathcal{H}$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, stacks, lie-groupoids

Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a Lie groupoid. The target map $t:\mathcal{G}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_0$ is a principal $\mathcal{G}$ bundle.

This article [Orbifolds as Stacks?](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0806.4160.pdf) by Eugene Lerman calls (in page $11$) this particular principal bundle to be the unit principal $\mathcal{G}$ bundle. So, for a Lie groupoid $\mathcal{G}$, this $\mathcal{G}$ bundle is a special element in $B\mathcal{G}$.

Let $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{H}$ be Lie groupoids.
For $B\mathcal{G}$, I have a special element $t:\mathcal{G}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_0$. For $B\mathcal{H}$, I have a special element $t:\mathcal{H}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{H}_0$. We can ask the follwing question.

> Are "the unit elemnts"  preserved by an arbitrary map of stacks $F:B\mathcal{G}\rightarrow B\mathcal{H}$ i.e., do we always have $F(t:\mathcal{G}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_0)=t:\mathcal{H}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{H}_0$ for any map of stacks $F:B\mathcal{G}\rightarrow B\mathcal{H}$.

This question **does not** make sense. As $F$ preserves fibers, $F(t:\mathcal{G}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_0)$ would be a principal $\mathcal{H}$ bunle of the form $Q\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_0$.  So, $F(t:\mathcal{G}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_0)$ which is of the form $Q\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_0$ **can not** be the principal $\mathcal{H}$ bundle $t:\mathcal{H}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{H}_0$.

We have principal $\mathcal{H}$ bundles $Q\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_0$ and $\mathcal{H}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{H}_0$. As base spaces are different there is no way (in general) to compare these two principal $\mathcal{H}$ bundles.

Suppose we are in a situation where $B\mathcal{G}\rightarrow B\mathcal{H}$ is coming from a morphism of Lie groupoids $\mathcal{G}\rightarrow \mathcal{H}$. 
Realising that there is an obvious map between base spaces of these two bundles namely $\phi:\mathcal{G}_0\rightarrow \mathcal{H}_0$ makes the question of looking for some relation between $Q\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_0$ and $\mathcal{H}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{H}_0$ more specific.
The question would then be,

> Is $Q\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_0$ same the pull back of $t:\mathcal{H}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{H}_0$ along $\phi:\mathcal{G}_0\rightarrow \mathcal{H}_0$.

In a very special case when this morphism of Lie groupoids $\phi:\mathcal{G}\rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ is a Lie groupoid extension i.e., when $\phi:\mathcal{G}_0\rightarrow \mathcal{H}_0$ is an identity map (and some thing extra), we can ask

> Is $Q\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_0$  same thing as $t:\mathcal{H}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{H}_0=\mathcal{G}_0$.

I could not see why this is true from definition of map of stacks but I feel this should be the case. Any comments are welcome.

Edit : A stack (over the category of manifolds $\text{Man}$) for me is a category $\mathcal{D}$ along with a functor $\mathcal{D}\rightarrow \text{Man}$ such that it is a category fibered in groupoids and some extra conditions. By an element of stack I mean an element (object) in the category $\mathcal{D}$.

Consider the special case when this map of stacks $B\mathcal{G}\rightarrow B\mathcal{H}$ is coming from a morphism of Lie groupoids $\mathcal{G}\rightarrow \mathcal{H}$. I will recall how one gets $B\mathcal{G}\rightarrow B\mathcal{H}$ from $\mathcal{G}\rightarrow \mathcal{H}$.

We first construct a $\mathcal{G}-\mathcal{H}$ bibundle given $\phi:\mathcal{G}\rightarrow \mathcal{H}$. We consider principal $\mathcal{H}$ bundle $t:\mathcal{H}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{H}_0$, pull it back along $\phi:\mathcal{G}_0\rightarrow \mathcal{H}_0$ to get a principal $\mathcal{H}$ bundle, now with the base $\mathcal{G}_0$ which is precisely $\mathcal{G}_0\times_{\mathcal{H}_0}\mathcal{H}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{H}_0$. The manifold $\mathcal{G}_0\times_{\mathcal{H}_0}\mathcal{H}_1$ has an action of $\mathcal{G}$ on it, given by $g.(x,h)=(t(g),\phi(g)h)$. With this action, it becomes a $\mathcal{G}-\mathcal{H}$ bibundle.

[image]

This $\mathcal{G}-\mathcal{H}$ bibundle gives morphism of stacks $B\mathcal{G}\rightarrow B\mathcal{H}$ the map is given by [composition of bibundle](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/303781/composition-of-bibundles). The object $\mathcal{G}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_0$ is mapped to $\left(\mathcal{G}_1\times_{\mathcal{G}_0}(\mathcal{G}_0\times_{\mathcal{H}_0}\mathcal{H}_1)\right)/\mathcal{G}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_0$
 which comes from following diagram

[image]

We have  $\left(\mathcal{G}_1\times_{\mathcal{G}_0}(\mathcal{G}_0\times_{\mathcal{H}_0}\mathcal{H}_1)\right)/\mathcal{G}_1=
\mathcal{G}_0\times_{\mathcal{H}_0}\mathcal{H}_1$.

So, the principal bundle is $\mathcal{G}_0\times_{\mathcal{H}_0}\mathcal{H}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_0$.

If $\mathcal{G}\rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ is a Lie groupoid extension, then we have $\mathcal{H}_0=\mathcal{G}_0$ and $\mathcal{G}_0\times_{\mathcal{H}_0}\mathcal{H}_1=\mathcal{H}_1$. 
So, $\mathcal{G}_0\times_{\mathcal{H}_0}\mathcal{H}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_0$ is just the target map $t:\mathcal{H}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{H}_0$.

So, if $F:B\mathcal{G}\rightarrow B\mathcal{H}$ is given by a morphism of Lie groupoids $\mathcal{G}\rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ which is a Lie groupoid extension, then $F(t:\mathcal{G}_1\rightarrow M)=t:\mathcal{H}_1\rightarrow M$.

Otherwise, it does not make sense to ask if $F$ takes unit principal bundle  of $\mathcal{G}$ to unit principal bundle of $\mathcal{H}$.

Comment: What do you mean by an element of a stack? For me a stack is a sheaf of groupoids, and the principal bundle $t:\mathcal G_1\to\mathcal G_0$ is an object in the groupoid $B\mathcal G(\mathcal G_0)$. A morphism of stacks $B\mathcal G\to\mathcal BH$ sends this to an object of $B\mathcal H(G_0)$, and if you present the morphism as a functor $F_i:\mathcal G_i\to\mathcal H_i$, you can check that this object is the principal $\mathcal H$-bundle $\mathcal H_1\times_{t,\mathcal H_0,F_0}\mathcal G_0$ (the map $F_i$ and functoriality is used to turn this into a principal bundle).

Comment: I think you mean to say "[---] If you present the morphism as a functor $F:\mathcal{G}\rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ [---]"...  @BertramArnold

Comment: There is something here which does not make sense. As any map of stacks $B\mathcal{G}\rightarrow B\mathcal{H}$ is fiber preserving, it takes an object $t:\mathcal{G}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_0$ in $B\mathcal{G}$ to some thing of the form $Q\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_0$ which can not be $t:\mathcal{H}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{H}_0$. I was having in mind the map of stacks coming from a Lie groupid extension (which is simply a morphism of Lie groupoids with same base i.e., $\mathcal{G}_0=\mathcal{H}_0$ with some extra condition on $\phi:\mathcal{G}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{H}_1$).

Comment: In that case, object $t:\mathcal{G}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_0$  goes to some thing of the form $Q\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_0$ in $B\mathcal{H}$. As $\mathcal{H}_0=\mathcal{G}_0$,  object $t:\mathcal{G}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_0$  goes to some thing of the form $Q\rightarrow \mathcal{H}_0$ in $B\mathcal{H}$. Now, I can ask if this $Q\rightarrow \mathcal{H}_0$ is same as that of the unit element $\mathcal{H}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{H}_0$ in $B\mathcal{H}$. This is what I meant to ask. I am editing the question so that it makes some sense. @BertramArnold

Comment: As you said a general morphism of stacks can't preserve "unit" principal bundles. If both stacks are presented by groupoids and the morphism is presented by a functor it sends the unit bundle of $\mathcal G$ to the pullback of the unit bundle of $\mathcal H$ along the object map of the functor (which should be something like the formula at the end of my previous comment), so in case of a Lie groupoid extension it does preserve unit bundles. All of this should more or less follow from the definitions, in particular how a Lie functor defines a fibered functor between the presented stacks.

Comment: @BertramArnold  Even in Lie groupoid extension it is not that obvious for me... Please wait for some more time so that I can write down what I am planning to write :D

Comment: @BertramArnold After writing it in detail, I feel this is not suitable for MO. As I have written anyways, do you want to comment on it? Is this is what you had in mind when you say it follows from definition?

Comment: @BertramArnold 
One thing that I do not understand is how did you figure out $F(t:\mathcal{G}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_0)$ has to be? I mean what is your definition of map of stacks $B\mathcal{G}\rightarrow B\mathcal{H}$ associated to a morphism of Lie groupoids $\mathcal{G}\rightarrow \mathcal{H}$. My definition (you can see in edit) involves some quotients and notion of bibundle and all which turns out to be $\mathcal{G}_0\times_{\mathcal{H}_0}\mathcal{H}_1$. Can you say how you associate a $B\mathcal{G}\rightarrow B\mathcal{H}$ given a map $\mathcal{G}\rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ ..

Comment: Morphisms of Lie groupoids define morphisms of prestacks and then morphisms of stacks by functoriality of stackification. If you unwrap the definitions this morphism of stacks will send trivialized $\mathcal G$-bundles (coming from maps $X\to \mathcal G_0$) to the corresponding trivialized $\mathcal H$-bundles (postcompose with the object map of the functor to get $X\to\mathcal H_0$). In general choose a local trivialization and patch the corresponding trivialized $\mathcal H$-bundles together. You can do this for the "universal" $\mathcal G$-bundle over $B\mathcal G$ to get the bibundle.

Comment: @BertramArnold Do you have a reference (paper/notes) where this is done in detail.. I think I need this kind of approach to appreciate more of what is going on..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more of a long comment, but since the question has been answered in the last edits I will post it as an answer.

There are multiple perspectives on the stack presented by a Lie groupoid $\mathcal G$: One is the fibered category of principal bundles which you use, another one is the sheafification of the presheaf of groupoids which sends $X$ to the groupoid with objects maps from $X$ to $\mathcal G_0$ and morphisms maps from $X$ to $\mathcal G_1$. These correspond to trivial principal bundles; in the stackification we have to replace our test manifold by a cover $U$ and consider trivial principal bundles on $U$ together with descent data on $U\times_X U$. You can check that these glue to a principal bundle on $X$. (If $\mathcal G = pt//G$, this is just the description of principal $G$-bundles by cocycles.)

Both descriptions are equivalent, and the principal bundle description is arguably nicer - it involves a short list of data and relations, whereas the stackification of the prestack requires you to allow all possible covers, then identify descent data on different covers when there is a common refinement, ... However this description only works well if we map into the stack $B\mathcal G$ (for instance, when evaluating it on a test manifold). When we map out of it, we usually use the cover coming from the Lie groupoid presentation:

If $\mathcal G$ and $\mathcal H$ are two Lie groupoids, one can ask what the groupoid of natural transformations between $B\mathcal G$ and $B\mathcal H$ is. By the Yoneda lemma, this should correspond to the evaluation of $B\mathcal H$ on $B\mathcal G$, and since the unit principal bundle defines a morphism $\mathcal G_0\to B\mathcal G$ which is a cover, this evaluation is just given by objects in $B\mathcal H(\mathcal G_0)$ together with an isomorphism between the two ways of pulling this object back to $\mathcal G_1$. You can check that this recovers the notion of a bibundle between Lie groupoids - the object in $B\mathcal H(\mathcal G_0)$ defines the right $\mathcal H$-bundle structure, and the isomorphism defines the left $\mathcal G$-bundle structure. From this description you can immediately derive all formulas for bibundles, e.g. the composition of bibundles, the bibundle associated to a functor, ...

Lastly, I think that while it's important to have a rigourous mathematical framework for stacks, for which fibered categories are certainly a good candidate, it's also important to have intuition about them, and for this I usually pretend that my stack is $BG$ when I map into it and the Cech groupoid of a cover of some manifold when I map out of it.

Comment: When you have a map of stacks $\mathcal{D}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ you want to think $\mathcal{C}$ as stack associated to a manifold $M$, some denote this by $\underline{M}=B\{M\rightrightarrows M\}$ and you want to think $\mathcal{D}$ as stack associated to a Lie groupoid $\mathcal{G}$ which is denoted by $B\mathcal{G}$... Is this what you mean in last paragraph?

Comment: "
If $\mathcal G$ and $\mathcal H$ are two Lie groupoids, one can ask what the groupoid of natural transformations between $B\mathcal G$ and $B\mathcal H$ is. By the Yoneda lemma, this should correspond to the evaluation of $B\mathcal H$ on $B\mathcal G$" - Wait.. this would be a 2-version of Yoneda I guess? And by the way what is $B\mathcal{H}(B\mathcal{G})$ (if not tautologically the Hom groupoid $\mathrm{Stacks}(B\mathcal{G},B\mathcal{H})$ of $1$-morhpisms (="Lie functors") from $B\mathcal{G}$ to $\mathcal{H}$)?

Comment: @Qfwfq Even I do not understand what is "evaluation of $B\mathcal{H}$ on $B\mathcal{G}$"... The $2$-version of Yoneda lemma I am aware of is (which you can find for example in page $23$ of Orbifolds as Stacks by Eugene Lerman) that, "given a manifold $M$ and a Lie groupoid $\mathcal{G}$, the category of maps/natural transformations from $\underline{M}$ to $B\mathcal{G}$ is evaluation of $B\mathcal{G}$ on $M$" i.e., the fiber $B\mathcal{G}(M)$ which are just principal $\mathcal{G}$ bundles over $M$.. I do not know if this can be generalized to the case  $B\mathcal{G}\rightarrow B\mathcal{H}$..

Comment: @Qfwfq appropriate thing on other side would be "Evaluation of $B\mathcal{H}$ on $B\mathcal{G}$" just like in case of $\underline{M}\rightarrow B\mathcal{G}$ it was evaluation of $B\mathcal{G}$ on $M$... What I know is there is a correspondence between maps of the form $B\mathcal{G}\rightarrow B\mathcal{H}$ and what are known as $\mathcal{G}-\mathcal{H}$ bibundles..

Comment: @PK: yep, that one you quote may indeed be called a "2-Yoneda". I was talking about a (hypothetical) version with objects of 2-categories (instead of objects of 1-categories) everywhere.

Comment: What I meant was that if $B\mathcal G$ was a manifold, we could use the (2-)Yoneda lemma to compute the groupoid of natural transformations. Furthermore since $B\mathcal H$ is a stack we could equally well describe this groupoid as descent data for any cover of $B\mathcal G$. Now it is not a manifold, but it has a cover by a manifold, so the groupoid of descent data still makes sense, and it can be computed to be the groupoid of bibundles.

Comment: After reading repeatedly (It is only my problem that I did not get it immediately), I could understand (guess) something in last but one paragraph. correct me if I am wrong.
Suppose I have a map $B\mathcal{G}\rightarrow B\mathcal{H}$. Consider the map of stacks $\underline{\mathcal{G}_0}\rightarrow B\mathcal{G}$. Then consider the composition $\underline{\mathcal{G}_0}\rightarrow B\mathcal{G}\rightarrow B\mathcal{H}$. This composition $\underline{\mathcal{G}_0}\rightarrow B\mathcal{H}$ should correspond to a $\mathcal{H}$ bundle over $\mathcal{G}_0$ say $Q\rightarrow \mathcal{H}_0$.

Comment: This is one of the data that need for a $\mathcal{G}-\mathcal{H}$ bibundle namely a $\mathcal{H}$ bundle whose base is $\mathcal{G}_0$. Now, some how this $Q$ has a $\mathcal{G}$ action that is compatible with $\mathcal{H}$ action giving a $\mathcal{G}-\mathcal{H}$ bibundle..

Comment: @Qfwfq Oh.. Ok Ok.. Do you  have any views to share on my question?